# Declaration merging and nested node_modules problem

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, node-modules, angular-translate

I have the next structure:

- @my/app

  - node_modules

    - @types/angular
    - @types/angular-translate
    - @my/library

      - node_modules

        - @types/angular

The problem is that `@types/angular-translate` extends the definitions of `@types/angular` through declaration merging.

On the other hand, it seems `@my/app` and `@my/library` somehow use different versions of `@types/angular`, even if I cannot find the difference comparing both package.jsons. That's why `@my/library` has its own node_modules with its own `@types/angular`.
But, since it has not its own `@types/angular-translate`, no one is adding the angular-translate types to the angular namespace and I'm getting the next error:

```
import {
    animate
} from "angular";
```

> TS2305: Module
>   '@my/app/node_modules/@my/library/node_modules/@types/angular"' has no
>   exported member 'translate'

As I said, I've found no differences between the versions of `@my/app` and `@my/library`. What can be wrong? I have more levels of nesting with libraries that use another version of `@types/angular`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't understand it 100%, but it seems different versions of nested `@types/angular` dependencies were causing the installation of that `@types/angular` inside `@my/library/node_modules`.

I've synchronized all versions of `@types/angular` between my libraries and not it is working.

After reading [this article at medium](https://medium.com/learnwithrahul/understanding-npm-dependency-resolution-84a24180901b) I guess it had to be with the installation order kept by npm to resolve the dependencies tree.